# reading and separating lines into linked list in C

Tags: c, text, linked-list, strtok

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Author; Title 
Author; Title 
etc...
```

I need to open this file and read it line by line into a linked list. So far I have this, but I'm not sure how to use strtok() since it's not reading correctly.
Can someone please help me with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
   char* author;
   char* title;
   struct node* next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *root;   
    struct node *c;     
    root = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
    root->next = 0;  
    c = root; 

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("books.txt", "r");

    char line[255];
    while( fgets( line, sizeof(line),f) != NULL)
    {
        char *token = strtok(line, ";");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
          fread( &c->author, sizeof( c->author ), 1, f );
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        fread( &c->title, sizeof( c->title ), 1, f );
        //printf("%s",&c->author);
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You need to *allocate memory* for the author and title fields in each new node and then *copy* the strings to these fields with e.g. `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks wrong. You always need to:

1. Read enough data.
2. Parse the data.
3. Allocate memory from heap.
4. Copy the data.

The `line` variable is just a temporary buffer, while the `char *author` and `char *title` variables can't live without allocated memory. Calling `fread()` is an utter nonsense in your code. You already called `fgets()`, that's where you read the data from the file. The rest should be only string operations.

A typical way is to get `char *start` pointed to the beginning of the data you are interested in, `char *end` to the first character behind the data you are interested in, and then request heap-allocated copy using `author = strndup(start, end-start)` or perform the same using a combination of `malloc()` and `memcpy()` or `strncpy()`.